# How to Compare multi dimentional string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I want to compare 2 fields. i.e Machine and Pass.

I want to concatenate 'Color' Depending upon the value of Machine and pass.

```
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color1       | Machine 1        | Pass 1 
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color2       | Machine 2        | Pass 1 
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color3       | Machine 1        | Pass 1 
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color4       | Machine 1        | Pass 2 
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color5       | Machine 2        | Pass 1 
--------------|------------------|------------
 Color6       | Machine 2        | Pass 2 
--------------|------------------|------------
```

I want results as follows.

1. Color1/Color3 for Machine1 & Pass1
2. Color2/Color5 for Machine2 & Pass2
3. Color4 for Machine1 & Pass2
4. Color6 for Machine2 & Pass2

I have no clue how to get this results. tried many ways but not getting it the way I want it

Comment: Supply the actual declaration of your array. Makes answering a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your answer,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ary = new[]
    {
        "Color1       | Machine 1     | Pass 1 ",
        "Color2       | Machine 2     | Pass 1 ",
        "Color3       | Machine 1     | Pass 1 ",
        "Color4       | Machine 1     | Pass 2 ",
        "Color5       | Machine 2     | Pass 1 ",
        "Color6       | Machine 2     | Pass 2 "
    };

    var seprated = from x in ary.Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                    select new
                    {
                        key = x[1].Trim() + "&" + x[2].Trim(),
                        value = x[0]
                    };

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var key in seprated.Select(x => x.key).Distinct())
    {
        var colors = seprated.Where(x => x.key == key).Select(x => x.value.Trim()).ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} for {1}", string.Join("/", colors), key));
    }

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

sb.toString() has result:

Color1/Color3 for Machine 1&Pass 1

Color2/Color5 for Machine 2&Pass 1

Color4 for Machine 1&Pass 2

Color6 for Machine 2&Pass 2

Comment: I like this answer because it is using the machine and pass as a unique key (forms some kind of relationship to the color#).

Answer (score 6):

First, what you really have here, conceptually, is a single dimension of a complex object that has both a color, machine, and pass value.  Storing that in a 2 dimensional array isn't a good idea.  A better representation is a `List` of some custom type, so let's do that conversion first.

First, we'll define a custom type to represent the input data:

```
public class MachinePass//TODO consider renaming
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Machine { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

then we'll parse our input and put it into the appropriate structure:

```
var list = new List<MachinePass>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var next = new MachinePass();
    next.Color = data[i, 0];
    next.Machine = data[i, 1];
    next.Pass = data[i, 2];
    list.Add(next);
}
```

Now that we have this, we can apply our business logic.  In this case what you're wanting to do is group these rows by both machine and pass, and then get the colors for those groups.  The `GroupBy` LINQ operator makes this super easy:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(row => new { row.Machine, row.Pass }
    , row => row.Color);
```

Then we can just print out the results of this query in the defined format:

```
foreach(var group in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} for {1} & {2}",
        string.Join("/", group),
        group.Key.Machine,
        group.Key.Pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var multidimensionalArray = new[,]
            {
                {"Color1", "Machine 1", "Pass 1"},
                {"Color2", "Machine 2", "Pass 1"},
                {"Color3", "Machine 1", "Pass 1"},
                {"Color4", "Machine 1", "Pass 2"},
                {"Color5", "Machine 2", "Pass 1"},
                {"Color6", "Machine 2", "Pass 2"}
            };

        var tuple = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
        for (var i = 0; i < multidimensionalArray.Length/3-1; i++)
        {
            tuple.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(multidimensionalArray[i, 0], multidimensionalArray[i, 1], multidimensionalArray[i, 2]));
        }

        foreach (var el in tuple.GroupBy(x => String.Format("{0} & {1}", x.Item2, x.Item3), y => y.Item1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("/", el) + " for " + el.Key);
        }
```

Comment: The OP says the input is a multi-dimentional string array, not a list of tuples.  Also, concatting the strings together is a very bug prone way of grouping on two values.  If the machine value of one is "12" with the pass of "3" it'll be grouped with a row where the machine value is "1" that has a pass of "23".  The use of a "&" delimiter helps a bit, but if the delimiters exist between each value in the underlying data then it can still fail.

Comment: I suspect, OP gets data from SQL, wants to campare strings only and looking for concept way.

Comment: I fail to see why it would matter if the data comes from SQL or not; it's still not the appropriate *concept* to concat the strings to create a key.  It can result in collisions.  The appropriate *concept* is to create a new object to represent multiple values that can have the appropriate definition of "equality".

Comment: Sure. But OP wants to campare multi-dimentional string array, not objects.

Comment: What about to organize data storage: make foreign keys to passes and machines. Connect to database using EntityFramework. Another way to create a SQL-view, which pivotes grouped data.

Comment: The OP starts with a multidimensional string array.  There is nothing in the question that would prohibit the creation of additional objects to be used to represent a multi-valued key.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I would use the exact same solution as used in my answer (bar the parsing) were this an EF query.  This is one of the advantages of LINQ; to abstract away the higher level idea of querying from the underlying implementation of what you are actually querying; query a flat file or a database looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a class definition so I am going to assume it is the following

```
class PaintMachineInfo
{
    public string ColorName {get; set;}
    public string MachineName {get; set;}
    public string Pass {get; set;}
}
```

You can easily get the results you want by using [`.ToLookup(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), what it will allow you to do is to provide a key and it will give you a IEnumerable of results that match that key.

I like to use a custom class for the lookup key instead of a `Tuple` because it makes it much more obvious what you are looking at and it is not too much code to create the class.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<PaintMachineInfo> info = GenerateInfo();

    var filteredResults = info.ToLookup(line => new PaintMachineLookup(line.MachineName, line.Pass), line => line.ColorName);

    //Contains a IEnumerable<string> containing the elements "Color1" and "Color3"
    var result1 = filteredResults[new PaintMachineLookup("Machine 1", "Pass 1")];

}

private static List<PaintMachineInfo> GenerateInfo()
{
    //...
}

class PaintMachineInfo
{
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}

internal class PaintMachineLookup
{
    public PaintMachineLookup(string machineName, string pass)
    {
        MachineName = machineName;
        Pass = pass;
    }
    public string MachineName { get; private set; }
    public string Pass { get; private set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int x = 27;
            x = x * 11 + MachineName.GetHashCode();
            x = x * 11 + Pass.GetHashCode();
            return x;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as PaintMachineLookup;
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return MachineName.Equals(other.MachineName) && Pass.Equals(other.Pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks the most promising, as I am guessing he doesn't already have an array (collection) of the three values together already, in order to take them apart, in order to put them together again...

Comment: @WonkotheSane in that case it is trivial to change `ToLookup` from using `.ToLookup(line => new PaintMachineLookup(line.MachineName, line.Pass), line => line.ColorName)` to `.ToLookup(line => new PaintMachineLookup(line[1], line[2]), line => line[0])` (assuming `info` is a `string[][]`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But he says he has a multi-dimensional array.  A `string[][]` is not a multi-dimensional array.  It's not quite so trivial to perform the conversion on a multidimensional array.

Comment: @Servy fair point. I am not sure what I would do to get it for a `string[,]`, I don't work with them that often.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain See my answer for one possibility.  While you could do it using some LINQ, I find it easier not to.